# Copy DataGridView's rows into another DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, clone

So basically I've got 2 `DataGridView` and I need to copy the rows from one to the other.

So far I've tried:

```
DataGridViewRowCollection tmpRowCollection = DataGridView1.Rows;

DataGridViewRow[] tmpRowArray = new DataGridViewRow[tmpRowCollection.Count];
tmpRowCollection.CopyTo(tmpRowArray, 0);            

DataGridView2.Rows.AddRange((DataGridViewRow[]) tmpRowArray));
```

But it keeps saying that

```
"Row provided already belongs to a DataGridView control."
```

So what's the best way to copy the content of the rows (both `DataGridView` have the same columns) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the function at the following link

```
private DataGridView CopyDataGridView(DataGridView dgv_org)
{
    DataGridView dgv_copy = new DataGridView();
    try
    {
        if (dgv_copy.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in dgv_org.Columns)
            {
                dgv_copy.Columns.Add(dgvc.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
            }
        }

        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_org.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_org.Rows[i].Clone();
            int intColIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv_org.Rows[i].Cells)
            {
                row.Cells[intColIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                intColIndex++;
            }
            dgv_copy.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dgv_copy.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgv_copy.Refresh();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cf.ShowExceptionErrorMsg("Copy DataGridViw", ex);
    }
    return dgv_copy;
}
```

http://canlu.blogspot.com/2009/06/copying-datagridviewrow-to-another.html

Comment: Thank you, but I doubt that this is the quickest way to copy these rows. I was searching if is possible to do this operation without a loop.

Comment: I'll accept this one because it seems the only way to get what I need.

Comment: Thank you. I added this (with slight modifications) as an extension method for DataGridViews.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first clone the row from the original then add to new view.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone.aspx

Comment: If i do `DataGridView2.Rows.AddRange((DataGridViewRow[]) tmpRowArray.clone()));` I get the same error. Do I have to clone each row in a loop? :|

Comment: unfortunately i think that is the case.  however if the original datagridview is bound to a dataset, you can bind the second datagridview to the same or clone of the dataset and get what you are after as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a backing DTO for this. Instead of dealing with the rows directly, create a DTO that contains all the columns of your GridViews, then use a List of them as your DataSource. Then, all you have to do to add/remove rows is to add/remove DTOs in the list.

Answer (score 0):

just write this:

```
copyDGV.DataSource = mainDGV.DataSource;
```

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Please format your code properly :) Best regards

Comment: @Dr.DEVELOPER: A good try, though it wouldn't be of any use for datagridviews without datasources.