# Unable to clone DataGridViewRow - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, datagridview, clone

There are numerous questiong about this on stack, however, I'm still unable to manage it.
I'm using solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336239/copy-datagridviews-rows-into-another-datagridview).

And, when I'm calling `row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_org.Rows[i].Clone();`I get an exception : `No parameterless constructor defined for this object`.
But DataGridView row does have a parameterless constructor! Could it be due to some stuff instide this row?
So, what is possible workarround here? I'm completely lost. Is there any other way to get either copy of DataGridView(Row) or same instance?

Comment: It works for me. You probably need to show more code. However, are you expecting the cell values to clone as well? Because cell values do not clone, only the row structure.

Comment: `row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_org.Rows[i].Clone();
            int intColIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv_org.Rows[i].Cells)
            {
                row.Cells[intColIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                intColIndex++;
            }
            dgv_copy.Rows.Add(row);
`
this code also copies cells, but I am getting an exception before that happens - on `.Clone` method.

Comment: I'm not convinced it is the clone method that is throwing. This generally discouraged, but can you screenshot where the debugger pops up the exception?

Comment: [here](https://yadi.sk/d/4ZUh_zPw3GyWbM)
The exception is thrown right after line with Clone.

Comment: In visual studio, go to Debug > Windows > Exception Settings then check the Common Language Runtime box, then debug your program. What line does it break on?

Comment: just like I said =( 
[Clone](https://yadi.sk/d/NsQUe5Qk3GyfB2)

Comment: Is that because you still have a manual break point on that line? Make sure you remove or disable all breakpoints first.

Comment: there is no breakpoint, it wouldn't have thrown an exception on a breakpoint, if there had been no exception as far as I understant

Comment: Whatever is wrong, it can't be determined by this information. I think the problem is not with code, but with possibly assembly references or solution problems, etc. Try clean, rebuild, restart, new project, etc. As I said, I am able to clone a row without error.

Comment: Ok, will try to do so! Thanks.